# PHP SQL Returning only one result

Tags: php, sql, pdo, wamp

Im trying to migrate my website from my local wamp project to my live server for testing, everything is working fine on my local site but on my live site the following code only returns one result. There are definitely multiple SQL entries that meet the sql query criteria. Any suggestions?

```
$opentickets = $db->query("SELECT tID, id, date, userid, category, department FROM ticket WHERE userid = '$_SESSION[id]' AND status='Open'");

if(count($opentickets) > 0) {
echo "<h2>Your open tickets:</h2>";
echo "<table class='table table-striped'>
    <tr>
    <th>Ticket</th>
    <th>Date Submitted</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Department</th></tr>";
$o = $opentickets->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "<tr><td><a href='ticket.php?id=" . $o['tID'] . "'>" . $o['tID'] . </td>";
echo "<td>" . $o['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $o['category'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $o['department'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
 }
else
{
echo "<h2>You have no open tickets</h2>";
}
```

Comment: Please, read manual for `fetch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not itterating over the results of your query, you are just fetching the first row...

Please reference to the examples on the [PHP Website](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) on how to do this.

I have just changed your code below, please check for the manuals for more information

```
while($o = $opentickets->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr><td><a href='ticket.php?id=" . $o['tID'] . "'>" .$o['tID'] . </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $o['date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $o['category'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $o['department'] . "</td></tr>";
}
```